# Do you have to marry in Paradise?

Tags: jannah

I am married but I not happy with who I am with, I don't even want to be married in the hereafter. If Allah permits me to Jannah can I choose to be single since you can have anything you want?

Abu’l-Qaasim (blessings and peace of Allah swt be upon him) said: “and there will be no one in Paradise who is unmarried.” Narrated by Muslim (2834)"

I want to live like a hermit and never see another person again just me and my animals I don't want Allah (swt) to change my mind and force me to want it because that's telling me what I want not giving me what I want. If that's Heaven then it doesn't sound like all that great. Please don't give annoying answers like lets work on getting into Jannah frist.

Answer (score 1):

Assalamu Alaikum. 
You are not happy with whom you are living.
But are u tied up?
Again gaining Jannah may depends on your partner too.So you had better live with someone withwhom you are happy. In this life you have manything to share & affect each other that may smooth your Next life In Shaa Allah.
Again,single?? 
           Yes some women like Rabeya Bosri(rahmahullah) was unmarried who was heavenly that we suppose.
Again some men like Imam An Nawabi( rahmahullah) was unmarried who was also heavenly as we suppose.
But being single for general persons like us is tougher.
Rather we should attempt to find a proper someone for us in this life.Again if u are not happy with your partner you should attempt to the way of Shariah.
May Allah bless you in Duniya  & Akhirat.
Amin.